# Is it possible to load a different HTML form onto a page by clicking a hyperlink or button?

Tags: php, html, forms, hyperlink

I have a number of different php-forms(25) that will handle some information. Instead of creating a different page for each of those forms, is it possible to be able to load a different form on the page just by selecting something from a list or hyper-link?

For example:

If I want to use form A then I click the link or button for form A, which then appears on the page when it reloads.

Let me know if you need me to explain it to you better lol.

[I want it to work the same way that this website does, you click the hyperlink and a different form appears.](http://citationmachine.net/index2.php?reqstyleid=0)

Comment: Sounds like your looking for Jquery

Comment: In what way would I use jQuery for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have the links that you click to select forms have GET variables attached to them, so that when the page reloads, you can use those variables to determine which form to show.
e.g.:

```
<a href="thispage.php?form=a">form a</a>
<a href="thispage.php?form=b">form b</a>
<a href="thispage.php?form=c">form c</a>

<?
switch ($_GET['form'])
{
    case 'a':
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="thispage.php">
            <!-- form a elements here :) -->
        </form>
        <?
        break;
    case 'b': // show form b
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="thispage.php">
            <!-- form b elements here :) -->
        </form>
        <?
        break;
    case 'c': // show form c
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="thispage.php">
            <!-- form c elements here :) -->
        </form>
        <?
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: I understand the premise of what you're talking about but how would I actually specify it to use "form a"? Where would the code for "form a" go and what would go where "case 'a': is?

Comment: Got it working exactly the way I want it to!

Thank you so much!